# Is there a "terminal" style program that talks to a server over http?

Tags: command-line, terminal, http

I'm looking for something that acts like a terminal but lets me have a "dialogue" with a server over http. Something like this :

```
$ connect http://myserver.com

Welcome to myserver.com  
Options
A - Fribble the obsticator
B - List Frogits
C - Show the log
Q - Quit

$ A
Obsticator fribbled
blah blah 
blah
$ C
Log file 
...

$ Q
Bye
```

I'm not looking for anything clever that tunnels an actual unix command-line over http. Nor a text-mode browser. This will talk to a simple custom server that knows its being accessed this way and that will return plain-text, not html.

But it must be over http, not a different protocol. And I don't want to be doing curl-like commands like

```
$ curl http://myserver.com?opt=A
```

It should be able to capture the URL once. And turning the command into a CGI argument should be transparent to the user.

Update: Also, I'm not bothered about keeping this dialogue open within a single connection, each command sent and received can be a separate http request. (In fact, that's better as it allows the server to be simpler)

Update 2 : The reason I want this is that I want to build a simple, small web-service API using Python Hug ( http://www.hug.rest/ ) but it would be convenient to have access to a couple of its actions directly from the command-line rather than the browser.

Rather than adding the extra complexity, of talking a different protocol and managing a separate interaction listener, on the server, it would be good to have a simple command-line client to talk to the API with standard http requests.

So, is there anything like this? (Before I sit down and write one.)

Comment: Short answer is NO, http is not design for this kind of interaction.

Comment: http was designed for sharing physics research papers .. it seems to have suffered considerable mission-creep since then :-) Is there any reason to think it would be a bad protocol for this?

Comment: The protocol just isn't really built that way. The closest thing I can think of is using `ncat` to connect to the port but, even then, you'd need to type in full HTTP requests and, in most cases, the connection will be closed before you even get one request off.

Comment: If you are willing to type `GET /?opt=A HTTP/1.0` and server doesn't close connection , go for it.

Comment: @Archemar Yes, what I'm looking for is something that does that GET  /?opt=A behind the scenes, but hides if from the user.

Comment: Why would the server need to keep the connection open? Each command can be a separate http request.

Comment: Is this question asking to do this with the Hypertext Transfer **Protocol**?  Or is the requirement that it do its work with the specific well-known **port** number?

Comment: @JdeBP I updated the question.

Comment: To access remote server, **SSH** *Secure Shell* is the only network protocol you should be using. Direct & Secure.

Comment: @drewbenn That seems like it could be a perfectly good answer to my question. Want to write it as one?

Comment: @CJDana if the command-line can access the server over https, would this be any less secure than accessing a web-interface in a browser?

Comment: Both of those methods use *http(s)* it would be preference at that point.

Answer (score 4):

You can use telnet to connect to the server, knowing that (
I am assuming here that you want to use a webserver to communicate with) you will need to operate within the contraints of the HTTP spec.
For example the specification   https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.txt
states:

> Origin servers MUST include a Date header field in all responses,  except in these cases: ...

here is the terminal output of a "conversation" I had with a webserver  over telnet.
Bearing in mind that the webservers configuration will determine how long the TCP connection is kept alive for - i.e. the time you have to type a properly formed HTTP request before the server will sever the TCP connection due to "inactivity".  but this is configurable.
If you enter each request before timeout, you will essentially be sending many HTTP requests and responses over a single continuous TCP connection.

```
% telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1           <---- this in where you type characters "interactively"            
Host: localhost          <---- this in where you type characters "interactively"
                         <-- per the HTTP specification this has to be an emtpy line
                             to tell the server you are done with your "message"



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 17 Sep 2016 07:38:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

45d
<html>
[truncated ... ]
</html>


0                      

GET / HTTP/1.1         <-- now you are back at prompt
Host: localhost            Note: you need to enter the `Host` header if you are talking 
                           to a webserver
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 17 Sep 2016 07:41:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

45d
<html>
[truncated]
```

Obviously to get a cleaner "dialogue" you would need to clean up the output from the webserver or your application that would be handling the requests.

The nginx `ttp_core_module` is responsible for managing the default type using
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type

To add headers you can use the `http_headers_module`
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't mind using `curl` as your backend, and you just don't want to have to type in the whole URL each time, you could run `curl` in a loop, something like this:

```
read -p "Server name: " s && curl -fs "$s" && while true; do read -p "$ " x && curl -fs "$s?opt=${x^^}" || break; done
```

which would also fit nicely into an `alias` if you didn't want to type or paste the whole thing in each time.

There's not a lot of error checking there, which is probably fine if you just want an easy way to talk to your own trusted server and aren't trying to hack your own script. A more advanced script could validate the server name or try to parse the returned web pages before displaying them, and of course both sides should defend against untrusted input.

I [added two options](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to `curl`:

- `-f` will exit with an error code `21` if the web page returns error `400` or above (useful for the `quit` command)
- `-s` silent mode won't show connection data for each command.

Other than that, you'll see exactly what your server outputs for each query.

Comment: One issue with this is that it doesn't URL encode what's sent to the server ... so if you try to send a line with spaces it blows up. Any idea how to do that in shell-script?

Comment: upvote for explanation of the `-f` and `-s` options

Answer (score 1):

OK.

Inspired by @drewbenn's answer, I wrote it myself in Python, using the Requests (http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library :

```
import requests
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]
print "Connecting ", url

r = requests.get(url)
print r.text
flag = True
while flag :
    s = raw_input()
    data = {"opt": s}
    r = requests.get(url, params=data)
    print r.text
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a RESTful HTTP API, particularly of the HATEOAS variety, then you could use Spring's rest-shell

https://github.com/spring-projects/rest-shell

Example usage:

```
http://localhost:8080:> discover
rel                href
========================================================
address            http://localhost:8080/address
family             http://localhost:8080/family
people             http://localhost:8080/person
profile            http://localhost:8080/profile

http://localhost:8080:> follow people
http://localhost:8080/person:> list
rel             href
===================================================
people.Person    http://localhost:8080/person/1
people.Person    http://localhost:8080/person/2
people.search    http://localhost:8080/person/search

http://localhost:8080/person:> get 1
...
```